# parse, PFQuery in cloud code how to filter columns?

Tags: parse-platform

I am writing a cloud code function in parse. I am running a query and I am trying to figure out how to filter columns of the object I am querying for.

So, I am querying for user objects:

```
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQuery.notEqualTo("username", username);
// so here how do I tell the query not return the values found in a column called "count"?
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **.select()**

Example below:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("testFunction", function(request, response) {

    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    userQuery.contains("objectId","7Ijsxy1P8J");

    //Here you say which columns you want, it will filter all other ones
    userQuery.select("objectId", "firstName", "lastName");

    userQuery.first({
        success: function(result) {
            response.success(result);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error("Failed with error ", error);
        }
    });
});
```

Over there I get a PFUser by its objectId but filtering only some fields. Hope it helps.